# show/hide on multiple div without defining div element id

Tags: html

first am sorry for bad English / grammar

am creating something where you show and hide.

but my problem is that when I click show/hide it only brings input box 1 on both buttons. and I want it to show/hide each box.

my problem is that. I don't want to use the id to define show/hide Element
because if I have more than 10 div with input boxes I have to define them all by getElementById I don't want that.

I want when I click on the show/hide it brings input box without getElementById
so that even if I have more then 10 input box to show I only click and show/hide without defining  its id

```js
function myFunction(event) {
            var x = document.getElementById("mydv");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
            
            x.parentNode.insertBefore(x, event.target.nextSibling);
        }
        document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
         if(event.target.className.includes("dv1")){
           myFunction(event);
          }
        });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> SHOW / Hide </title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <div id="mydv" style="display:none;"> 
    <p>input box 1
      <input type="text" name="textfield">
    </p>
    </div>
      <button class="dv1">SHOW/HIDE</button>
     </li>
     
     <li><div id="mydv" style="display:none;"> 
      <p>input box 2
      <input type="text" name="textfield">
    </p> 
    </div>
      <button class="dv1">SHOW/HIDE</button></li>
    </ul>
    
    </body>
    
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and lazy answer to your problems - if you are going to keep your current hierarchy, you can simply find DIV tag inside your LI parentNode (since its the only DIV tag).

Basically it goes like this - button press -> change focus from button to parentNode LI -> finds DIV.

in short - in `function myFunction(event)` change

```
var x = document.getElementById("mydv");
```

to

```
var x = event.target.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("DIV")[0];
```

Working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/w2a9zg46/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to specify an element on a page, that can be similar in every way to other elements except perhaps text content or something else, realistically you need an id, as this is how JavaScript defines a unique element.

But what you can do, is change your HTML button, to contain a rel, which is an attribute, and then get that attribute and use that to specify which element id you're looking for.

You can then call a function and simply pass "this" as an argument.

**HTML :**

```
<button onclick="hideShow(this)" rel="mydv">Show/Hide</button>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
<script>

function hideShow(elem){

  var ele = document.getElementById(elem.getAttribute("rel"));

  if(ele.style.display == "none"){
    ele.style.display = "block";
  }
  else{
  ele.style.display = "none";
  }

}

</script>
```

If you are absolutely abhorrent to using ID's, you can use child nodes and specify which child by number, but this means if ever you change anything, you will break your code, which is foolish. I recommend using unique ID's and simply changing your code in the above ways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that getElementById refers to the first element with that id. It simply ignores everything else. Using the same id for more than one element is a bad practice. An id should be a unique reference to that element, use class instead.